# In an alternating current circuit, the current in the circuit is given by

Tags: derivatives

$$i=\frac{v}{\sqrt{R^2+(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2}}$$

I know we have to differentiate it with respect to $~w~$ and then equate it zero, but the answer is way too confusing, so could you please help me with the derivation?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdw+v%2F%5Csqrt%7BR%5E2%2B(w+L-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bw+C%7D)%5E2%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be posted as a comment instead as an answer. But it is too long to be edited in the comments section.

$$i=\frac{v}{\sqrt{R^2+(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2}}$$

Why do you have to differentiate it with respect to $~w~$ and then equate it zero ?

Probably because you are looking for the maximum value of $i$. True or not ?

If true, before starting a "difficult" calculus  take the time to reflect. (In fact not a difficult calculus, but that is another story).

$i$ is maximum when $\sqrt{R^2+(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2}$ is minimum.

Then $(R^2+(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2)$ must be minimum.

Then $(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2$ must be minimum.

So, you could  differentiate it with respect to $~w~$ and then equate it zero , which is much simpler than what you intended to do at first.

But why not  taking the time to reflect a bit more ?

Obviously $(wL-\frac{1}{wC})^2$ is minimum when it is equal to $0$. Thus 
$$LCw^2=1$$
$$w=\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}$$
$$i_{maximum}=\frac{v}{R}$$

Comment: That’s a nice way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Writing
$$i=v\left(R^2+\left(wL-\frac{1}{wC}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}$$ gives
$$i=-\frac{1}{2}v\left(R^2+\left(wL-\frac{1}{wC}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}\left(2\left(wL-\frac{1}{wC}\right)\times\left(L+\frac{1}{w^2C}\right)\right)$$